# How can I send a Tmux prefix command from outside?

Tags: tmux

I'm writing a `Rakefile` to configure Tmux on my machines. After installing [Tmux Plugin Manager](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm) you're supposed to do `prefix + I`. I want to do that from my `Rakefile`.

I've been reading into the `$ tmux send-keys` command but I haven't been able to figure out how to send a prefix (and on the same not, I'm not even sure `send-keys` is the way to go).

Basically I want to start a Tmux session in detached mode and pass `prefix + I`, from the shell. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this @christopher?

Comment: I didn't. Had to put a TODO on my project until somebody figures it out for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you don't send prefix commands into tmux-- you run the tmux command directly that the keyboard shortcuts would run.

For your specific case, read the source code of Tmux Plugin Manager. See what it does when  `prefix + I` is used, and then run the same commands yourself. It probably amounts to downloading and copying some files into `~/.tmux/plugins/`